# Adjusting a MST to account for O(1) changes to edge weights

Tags: graph, tree, minimum-spanning-tree

Let `G = (V,E)` be an undirected graph. Let `w(e)` be a weighting function with positive weights. Let `T` be a minimum spanning tree of `G` with respect to `w`.

Given a set of edges `S`, where `S` is a subset of `E(G)`, define a new weighting function `Q` as `Q(e) = w(e)` if `e` is not in `S`, and `Q(e) = w(e)+100` if `e` is in `S`. Design an algorithm that accepts as input, `G`, `T`, `w` and a set `S`, `|S| = 10` and outputs a minimum spanning tree w.r.t. `Q`. Make it run in `O(V+E)` time.

Ok: what I've learned since I originally asked this question is that partitioning an MST is to "break apart" a single edge, which makes two separate components, each MST's of the vertices in their own components. So, in this problem, the edges in S might break up the MST into smaller MST's (11, right?). I have to find the lightest edges that connect one component to another.

My plan is to start at one vertex and expand with BFS until I cover an entire one of these components. For every u in the component, `u.color = black`. Then, I go back and cover the component again with BFS, this time finding all the edges that connect to vertices that are not colored black, therefore not contained within the component, and crossing the existing cut. The vertices opposite of these edges are placed in a Queue R. Once I am done, I `u = RemoveMin(R)`, which is runs `O(lgE)`. Since it will only be called every time I cover a component, it will run overall at a max of `10*O(lgE)`, which is still `O(lgE)`. So once I remove u, I perform BFS on the new component, so that all u.color = black in that component. I go through all the black vertices again so that I may queue all the white vertices with updated keys into R. I do `u = RemoveMin(R)`.

So I really think that this works and is proveable. Can anyone suggest something similar?

Any help, however small, would be appreciado.